# NLog custom target runtime dependency

Tags: c#, nlog

**Problem:** 
My database logic placed in some the big `DataBaseObject`. It contains methods, connection strings and everything what I need for this logic layer. How can I put it in NLog custom target in runtime?

**This works nearly fine (see remarks):**

```cs
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using Data.Base.Object.Namespace;

namespace MyNamespace 
{ 
    [Target("DatabaseLog")] 
    public sealed class DatabaseLogTarget: TargetWithLayout 
    { 
        private IDataBaseObject _db;

        public DatabaseLogTarget()
        {

        }

        [RequiredParameter] 
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
        { 
            Save(logEvent); 
        } 

        private void Save(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
        { 
            if (_db == null) { _db = new DataBaseObject(ConnectionString); }
            _db.Log();
        } 
    } 
}
```

**This not working, but what I need:**

```cs
using NLog;
using NLog.Config;
using NLog.Targets;
using Data.Base.Object.Namespace;

namespace MyNamespace 
{ 
    [Target("DatabaseLog")] 
    public sealed class DatabaseLogTarget: TargetWithLayout 
    { 
        private IDataBaseObject _db;

        public DatabaseLogTarget(IDataBaseObject db)
        {
            _db = db;
        } 

        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
        { 
            Save(logEvent); 
        } 

        private void Save(LogEventInfo logEvent) 
        {           
            _db.Log();
        } 
    } 
}
```

**Remarks:**

1. I don't want to use the standard DataBase target, because in this case I will need to support two configs and the database work logic will be in different places.
2. The current version has a bottleneck in this place:

```cs
if (_db == null) { _db = new DataBaseObject(ConnectionString); }
```

... because DataBaseObject is really big.

3. I read something about dependency injection, but this technique leads to some package dependences. It's means that there are more places where everything can break down.

Comment: what's the scope of `DataBaseObject`? Is it per logevent, or is there 1-2 in the application?

Comment: I did not quite understand the question. I use DataBaseObject in five apps: Console for test, WCF service, two Web service and ASP.NET app for work. And one-two DataBaseObject for one instance / session. The current version creates one DataBaseObject for each method, which I want to log.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GlobalDiagnosticsContext](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_GlobalDiagnosticsContext.htm) to store the `IDataBaseObject` and use it in your target.

Somewhere in your code:

```
GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("key1", myDbObject);
```

and read it in your target:

```
var myDbObject = GlobalDiagnosticsContext.GetObject("key1");
```

Note: if you need a limited scope, you could also use the [MappedDiagnosticsContext](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_MappedDiagnosticsContext.htm) (scope per thread) or the [MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/T_NLog_MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.htm) (scope per thread, including async `Tasks`)

Comment: Not for me. I don't want to get the global variables hell.

Now I change my current version via the standard database target, but pass connectionString and commandText in runtime.

Comment: Therefor I asked for the scope. Anyway, you could use `MappedDiagnosticsContext` / `MappedDiagnosticsLogicalContext` then?